# What is the alternative for sc:EditFrame in Sitecore MVC

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, page-editor

The project I'm working on is a new Sitecore 8 site build using MVC and with a demand for page-editor support. The simple fields are being addressed with the `FieldRenderer.render()` method, but there are also some droplink and multilist fields that need to be available in page editor.
In webforms you could use the `sc:editframe` control for that, but how can I get the same functionality while using Sitecore MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not already, I highly recommend using [GlassMapper](http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc.aspx) to map your Sitecoce object to strongly typed objects in your code.

With Glass, you can then use the [BeginEditFrame](http://www.glass.lu/en/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial14.aspx) concept to replace the `sc:EditFrame` functionality of WebForms.

To take it a step further, look to implement [edit frame buttons](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-sitecore-editframe-in-pageedit/) (this link is not Sitecore 8 specific, but the method to implement edit frame buttons is the same) in the core database to allow a very-friendly Experience Editor experience.

Comment: Is using GlassMapper the only option for using the concept of editing more complicated fields with Sitecore MVC while using the Experience Editor? Since I'm just starting with Sitecore, i'm a bit reluctant in adding yet another new product to the solution.

Comment: @MyriamDeScheemaecker: While I still recommend using Glass, it is not required to edit fields in page editor.  Check out Göran's post: https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/how-to-use-editframe-in-sitecore-mvc/ (he copied how Glass implemented edit frames)

Comment: Thank you, Göran's post is exactly what I am looking for at this moment. I will sure take a look at Glass for future projects.

Answer (score 3):

Just an FYI in Sitecore 8.2 there is support for edit frames:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions
```

Then

```
@using(Html.EditFrame(...)) {...}
```

Comment: My advice would be. If you are still developing the project, before production release, update. Otherwise, think about it first.